# How to use logger.exception is True in if statement

Tags: python, smtp

I am using STMPHandler to log exceptions of a python script.  How would I to write a conditional statement after my except block which would state, `if handler sends e-mail do this`?

I use a try block after the class below. and my except block reads as `except:
    logger.exception("Something has gone wrong!")` and fires an email with my traceback and my message.

```
class TlsSMTPHandler(logging.handlers.SMTPHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.

        Format the record and send it to the specified addressees.
        """
        try:
            import smtplib
            import string # for tls add this line
            try:
                from email.utils import formatdate
            except ImportError:
                formatdate = self.date_time
            port = self.mailport
            if not port:
                port = smtplib.SMTP_PORT
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.mailhost, port)
            msg = self.format(record)
            msg = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\nDate: %s\r\n\r\n%s" % (
                            self.fromaddr,
                            string.join(self.toaddrs, ","),
                            self.getSubject(record),
                            formatdate(), msg)
            if self.username:
                smtp.ehlo() # for tls add this line
                smtp.starttls() # for tls add this line
                smtp.ehlo() # for tls add this line
                smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
            smtp.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg)
            smtp.quit()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

Comment: Why the `except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): raise`, then a blank except? Why not just use `except Exception:` instead? Or are you expecting a `GeneratorExit` exception here?

Comment: My exception comes from logger.exception which is defined after, if anything between the try, except block has an error, my exception is thrown and an email is sent, I would like to use another statement after this logger.exception which states if logger.exception == True.  But I do not know the correct syntax for it.